# Gatsby.jsで生成したHTMLのリンクついて教えてください

Tags: javascript, gatsby

`gatsby build`コマンドでpublicフォルダに出力されるHTML間でページ遷移を行いたいのですが、
ローカルで動作させる場合、リンクが`file:///pandas-and-bananas/`のように相対パスになってしまい開くことができません。
HTMLやJavaScriptの知見がなく、どのようにしたらローカルで動作するリンクとして出力することができるのかご教示いただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `file:///pandas-and-bananas/` は相対パスではなくて file URI なのですが、これが正確に生成されている URI でしょうか？　この URI だけだと何故ファイルが開けないのか分からないので、もう少し具体的な説明が欲しいです。また、`gatsby build` は何のオプションも無しにこれだけ実行しましたか？

Answer (score 3):

Webサーバーを起動する必要があります。

Gatsbyが入っているということは、npmを使っていると思いますので、[serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)を利用してみると良いでしょう。

```sh
npm i -g serve
```

インストール完了後、`serve`コマンドが利用可能です。Gatsbyの出力先の`public`ディレクトリ内に`cd`コマンド出入り、`serve`を実行します。

デフォルトだとhttp://localhost:5000をブラウザで開けば確認できるでしょう。